# 2 mysql table and swift tableview

Tags: ios, mysql, json, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to write a small application with swift but I'm new in programming .
I have 2 tables in the database (Singers and Songs). I show Singers list in TableView with json . But then I do not have the slightest idea what to do.

1.select singer 2. select singer's song 3. show song's video

singers table singerid,singername ==> 
songs table   songid,songname,songvideurl,singerid ==>

Comment: Why do not you join these two tables and make one table and then call it with a single json object. After that parse and then tabulate it.

Comment: I guess you have to make 2 UITableViewControllers( singerViewController will push to SongViewController and this will push for playing song) and 1 UIViewController(for playing songs)  and get the data based on each push

Comment: Do you wonder if there is such an example . I could not find a good example on the internet.

Comment: do you have an example?  @Shashi3456643

Comment: I'm confused , please help me

Comment: I have posted my answer I hope it should help.

Comment: so I have to use either a single statement. only 1 json join 2 table.  YES?

Comment: I don't think so you need to join two tables u can pull songs based on singerid. And particular song using songid from song table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so its very difficult task. you can do following way

```
//On singerTableViewController on cell selection
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   SongTableViewController *songTableViewController=<get from story board>
    songTableViewController.singerID=<get from your array>//you can use this to load song list from song table

[self.navigationController pushViewController:songTableViewController animated:YES];
}

//On SongTableViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 // get all songs list using singer ID and fill your song table
}

//On SongTableViewController on cell selection
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   SongPlayViewController *songPlayViewController=<get from story board>
    songPlayViewController.songID=<get from your array>//you can use this to play song on SongPlayViewController

[self.navigationController pushViewController:songPlayViewController animated:YES];
}

//On SongPlayViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 // play your song based on your songID
}
```